# ANTLR for Python: Name 'Lexer' is not defined

Tags: python-2.7, antlr4

I just executed the script here
https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/python-target.md
`$ antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python2 Hello.g4`

and I successfully got the files:

```
    `12/05/2022  07:18 AM               250 Hello.interp`
    `12/05/2022  07:18 AM                31 Hello.tokens`
    `12/05/2022  07:18 AM               990 HelloLexer.interp`
    `12/05/2022  07:18 AM             1,711 HelloLexer.py`
    `12/05/2022  07:18 AM                31 HelloLexer.tokens`
    `12/05/2022  07:18 AM               392 HelloListener.py`
    `12/05/2022  07:18 AM             2,351 HelloParser.py`
    `11/29/2022  02:42 PM               544 main.py`
```

But when I run the main.py, I got an error message
`NameError: name 'Lexer' is not defined`

Where is the `Lexer` definition in ANTLR for Python?
How to overcome the error?

Comment: The compiler doesn't know what "Lexer" is because it doesn't have the sources for Antlr4 Python2 target. "Once you've generated the lexer and/or parser code, you need to download the runtime." Also, are you sure you want to use Python2 instead of Python3?

Comment: Yeah,  I just know that Antlr4 wasn't installed completely. I use Python2 because I got error when I use Python3